# Edit top 3 lines of large csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

Have used PowerShell in the past but I'll be honest. I haven't much of a clue.

I am looking to do the following with a large amount of csv files that are around 100mb each.

1. Remove entirely the top line in the file.
2. Swap the 2nd and 3rd lines around.
3. Save the file back in its original name.
4. loop round this for all the files in the folder.

From what I can gather, stripping out the top line is relatively straightforward, but swapping the next two lines round seems more difficult?

Comment: It may be useful to consider the CSV files to just be text files in this case.

Comment: What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that these CSV files dont' have any multi-line value entries, you can treat it as any other text file:

```
$null,$Second,$Third,$Rest = Get-Content -Path data.csv
$Third,$Second,$Rest |Set-Content -Path data.csv
```

Comment: I was going to say that a streamreader might be required for large files but 100mb does not meet that threshold for me.

Comment: @Matt agreed, the above should be fine for 100mb files

Answer (score 1):

Different approach using less memory but a temp file.

```
ForEach ($File in (Get-ChildItem *.txt)){
  Remove-Item .\MyTemp
  Rename-Item $File .\MyTemp
  $Lines = Get-Content .\MyTemp | Select-Object -First 3
  $Lines[2,1] | Set-Content $File
  Get-Content .\MyTemp | Select-Object -Skip 3 | Add-Content $File
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will give these a whirl when I get chance. Many thanks